# Time for Langton's ant to cover a "square" torus

Tags: co.combinatorics, ds.dynamical-systems, random-walks, cellular-automata

[Langton's ant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Langton%27s_ant) is a cellular automaton running as follows:

> Squares on a plane are colored variously either black or white. We
>   arbitrarily identify one square as the "ant". The ant can travel in
>   any of the four cardinal directions at each step it takes. The ant
>   moves according to the rules below:
>
> - At a white square, turn 90° right, flip the color of the square, move forward one unit
> - At a black square, turn 90° left, flip the color of the square, move forward one unit

We consider Langton's ant on a torus $n$ by $n$ gridded such that all the squares are white.

**Preliminary question**: Is it true that Langton's ant will visit every square, for all $n$?

*Remark*: I've checked it's true for $n \le 1000$. In fact Langton's ant could enter into a local cycle without having visiting every square (see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/199861/34538)),  so the fact that such phenomena can't appear must be proved.

If so, let $s_n$ be the number of steps Langton's ant needs for visiting all the squares.

**Question**: what's the asymptotic of $s_n$?

$\small{ \begin{array}{c|c}
 n  &2&3& 4& 5& 6&  7&  8&  9&  10&  50 &     100 &     500  \newline 
                             \hline
s_n &3&12&41&62&166&113&318&281&692&57672  &  225905 &     12740527 
\end{array} }  $

*Remark*: Following the table above, this asymptotic seems to be $\frac{4}{\pi}(nln(n))^2$, [as for the random walk](https://mathoverflow.net/q/199467/34538).

$\small{ \begin{array}{c|c}
 n  &1000&2000 & 5000 &6000&   10000&  11000 &     12000 &     13000 &     14000  \newline 
                             \hline
\frac{4(nln(n))^2}{s_n} &2.919&2.196&2.177&1.770&1.506&2.067&1.734&1.502&1.911 
\end{array} }  $

*Remark*: This new data suggests that there is no asymptotic, because for $n$ large  $\frac{4(nln(n))^2}{s_n}$ seems bounded in $[1,4]$ but not convergent.

For $n=50$ and the ant starting "up" at position $(25,25)$, the grid looks as follows at step $s_n$:

[image]

Now by encoding square's color by how many times it was visited (no effect on the rules) we get:

[image]

And for $n=500$ at step $s_n = 12740527$:

[image]

These pictures was computed online at  http://www.turnerbohlen.com/langtonsant/

And for $n=5000$ at step $s_n = 3331448985$:

[image]

For comparison, this last picture was generated from a *uniform random walk* for $n=5000$ (covered after $2410514205$ steps):

[image]

These two last pictures were computed by Sage, with [this code](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1jObtdxMKRBQcmXJjEsVCe01lBOTQldju).

Comment: Can you supply a picture of the ants path when placed in a 50 by 50 square before the path self-intersects because of the toroidal condition?  If r_n is the sequence where r_n steps are taken "before a wraparound effect occurs", perhaps that will suggest asymptotics of s_n.

Comment: what guarantees that the ant will visit all the squares?

Comment: @TheMaskedAvenger:  I don't understand your suggestion. Anyway, you can compute such a picture on http://www.turnerbohlen.com/langtonsant/  Under the table, the asymptotic seems to be the same as a random walk: $\frac{4}{\pi}(nln(n))^{2}$.

Comment: @Fry: You're completely right, this is also a problem. In fact the ant could enter into a local cycle without having visiting every square. The fact that such phenomena can't appear must be proved.

Comment: The website only shows covered squares, not the path that was taken.  I was hoping for a series of pictures, one showing a path of 8 steps (with some direction arrows, one of  16 steps, one of 32 steps, and one of 64, showing the ant's trajectory as a red curve superimposed on the grid.

Comment: Out of curiosity, suppose that we forget about colors and have the ant randomly turn $90^\circ$ left or right with probability 1/2 for each, and then walk one step forward. What is the expected number of steps to visit all the squares on an $n\times n$ (or even $m\times n$) torus?

Comment: @RichardStanley: for $n \times n$ torus, heuristically, the asymptotic should be the same because most of the time is used for visiting the last small areas, whereas the others squares look randomly distributed black/white, and on such random pattern the path of the ant should be randomly left/right. Now for $n \times m$ torus the situation could be quite different, see [this new post](http://mathoverflow.net/q/199861/34538)

Comment: @Sébastien Palcoux: can one prove that for the random walk I described above on the $n\times n$ torus, the cover time is asymptotically $\frac{4}{\pi}(n\log n)^2$?

Comment: @RichardStanley: I don't know. But for Langton's ant, I've edited new data suggesting that there is no asymptotic.

Comment: @RichardStanley I believe that the answer to your question is "yes". The argument would follow the same pattern as in DPRZ. The latter dealt with the case of independent steps - in your situation you have an underlying 4-states Markov chain, and the computation is messier, but the basic estimate (which involves claiming that the  probability of hitting a ball of radius R/2 before you hit a ball of radius 2R, starting on the boundary of a ball of radius R, is "essentially" 1/2) should still hold.

Comment: In the pictures showing how often the ant appears on a square, could you give a legend for what color means what frequency?

Comment: @ZsbánAmbrus: for the last picture, the ant visits a square between $1$ and (around) $300$ times. The red corresponds to $1$, the violet to $300$ and all the intermediate frequencies are uniformly distributed in the visible spectrum.

Comment: So funny: having first seen the related thread about an nx6 torus, when I saw this one, the title appeared to tell me "and now it's time for Langton's ant to cover a square torus" :-) :-)

Answer (score 4):

I have been playing with Langtons ant for a while now,
Have a look at this video which shows 10^30 iterations.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LXDBJ4zKWvI

And the wave equations are here with octave script and a link to octave online where you can run the math.

https://sites.google.com/site/extendedlangtonsant/

Hope someone finds this useful.

Graham

Comment: What is the size of the torus in your video?

Comment: 256x256     with 8 bit grey scale.

Comment: Are you sure that there are $10^{30}$ iterations? (because  $s_{250}<10^7$)

Comment: 2^30 not 10 sorry, typo.

Comment: The 3d plots are generated by plotting 256 groups of 256^3 iterations.

Comment: I have now made the langtons ant engine available online.
http://buzwordsalad.com/one.html