# Does Langton's ant cover every n by 6 gridded torus?

Tags: co.combinatorics, ds.dynamical-systems, computer-science, cellular-automata

This post follows [this other post](https://mathoverflow.net/q/199543/34538) about times cover by [Langton's ant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Langton%27s_ant) of $n$ by $n$ gridded torus.

For $n$ by $n$ gridded torus, I've checked for $n \le 1000$ that the ant covers all. This fact needs to be proved for every $n$, but this should be not surprising.

Contrariwise, we can easily checked that for the $n$ by $2$ gridded torus and $n \ge 3$, the ant enters into a cycle before covering the torus:

[image]

Idem for the $n$ by $4$ gridded torus and $n \ge 5$:

[image]

Now for $n$ by $6$ (with $n \ge 5$) there is a problem.
For $n=50$, it is not yet covered after around $10^4$ steps:

[image]

and it is not yet covered after around $10^5$ steps:

[image]

in fact I've checked that it's also not covered after $10^7$
 steps.

So there are two possibilities:

- for $n$ by $6$ gridded torus, the covering needs a long time, but finite (checked for $n \in [5, 60]$).
- $\exists n_0$ such that the ant covers $n_0$ by $6$ but **not** $n$ by $6$ for $n > n_0$.

**Question**:  Does Langton's ant cover every n by 6 gridded torus ($n \ge 5$)?
[If yes, what's the asymptotic of the covering time? Else, what's $n_0$?]

*If no:* i.e. if the ant enters into a cyclic pattern of width $n_0$ then we need *a priori* to go at least up to the step $4 \cdot 6 \cdot n_0 \cdot 2^{6 \cdot n_0}$ for checking that, which could become out of computation.

*If yes:* let $s^m_n$ be the number of steps Langton's ant needs for covering the $n$ by $m$ torus.

$\scriptsize{ \begin{array}{c|c}
 n  &10&20&30&40&50&60&70&80  \newline 
                             \hline
s^6_n &977&17623&87113&3135267&19563171&331665879&4738404219&44105120036 \newline 
                             \hline
s^n_6 &240&6708&166542&2027581&32781038&220780386&4820615241&76325278885 \newline 
                             \hline
n/ln(s^6_n) &1.45&2.04&2.6373&2.6741&2.9781&3.0581&3.1419&3.2639 \newline 
                             \hline
n/ln(s^n_6) &1.82&2.26&2.4952&2.7543&2.8892&3.1229&3.1395 &3.1925
\end{array} }  $

This new data (sage computation) suggests that:  $s^6_n \sim s^n_6 \sim e^{n/c}$, with $c \sim 3$.

*Remark*: we can checked that there is no such a problem for the $n$ by $3$ or $5$ or $7$ $\dots$ gridded torus, but there is the same problem for the $n$ by $8$ or $10$ or $12$ $\dots$ gridded torus (at least up to $18$).

The pictures was computed online on http://www.turnerbohlen.com/langtonsant/

Comment: Where does 4.6 come from (in your upper remark)? $\;$

Comment: @RickyDemer: for $n_0$ by $6$ there are $6n_0$ squares and each square can have two states (black or white) so we get $2^{6n_0}$. Next about the position of the ant we have to multiply by $6n_0$, and about its state (up, down, left or right), we have to multiply by $4$. So finally, we get $4.6n_0.2^{6n_0}$.

Comment: That would give $\: 24\cdot n_{\hspace{.02 in}0} \cdot 2^{6\cdot n_{\hspace{.02 in}0}} \:$, $\:$ not $\: 4.6n_0.2^{6n_0} \;$. $\;\;\;\;$

Comment: @RickyDemer oh I see, for me $4.6$ meant $4 \times 6$, sorry. I've changed that because it's confusing.

Comment: I'm not sure how much this would help, but one could try splitting the grid into congruent pieces and computing a lookup table with [after_colors,exit_edge] for each possible [entry_edge,before_colors]. $\:$ (Such a table could presumably be compressed, and might reveal that some a-priori-possible color configurations of the pieces are not actually possible.) $\;\;\;\;$

Comment: Since this torus has a different shape, initial orientation matters.  Did you check for both orientations? and are the numbers the same?

Comment: @TheMaskedAvenger: You're right, I will check with the other initial direction. I believe the numbers should not be the same, but the asymptotic should be the same.

Comment: Following up on Ricky Demer's suggestion, it seems natural to me to replace the current system with a slightly more complicated one: for n=6, have a six-square ring replaced by a number in [0,63], with 144 combinations possible for entry and exit points, of which only 48 are used.  Although this only halves the number of steps, using this representation may allow some number theoretical analysis to show how quickly certain configurations are reached.  Gerhard "Also Has Small Transition Table" Paseman, 2015.03.13

Comment: I made an erroneous remark, which was partly true. Using a certain indexing of entry and exit points of a ring, one sees that the dynamic induces a parity change between the (indices of) entry and exit points.  As a result, the dynamic when translated in ring form will "collapse" the number of possible states to at most 32, and with an even number of rings, half the rings will always be exited at an odd-indexed point, and the other half at an even indexed point.  Perhaps this collapse continues with pairs of rings?

Comment: The Cohen-Kung theorem mentioned in the Wikipedia article suggests to me the possibility that one orientation may cover the torus while the other may not.  It might be insightful for the two-by and four-by tori to consider all possible colorings as well as orientations to see which lead to covers and which do not, at least for small values of n.

Comment: @TheMaskedAvenger: I've edited the data for the other initial direction.

Comment: By looking the ant moving in the $n$ by $6$ torus, inducing the evolution of the black/white pattern, I thought that the key is to understand what this system is computing.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this helps but I have derived a wave equation for langtons ant so you can now evaluate it algebraically.

Octave online code available to support the math
https://simple.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/User:Dakoder#/search

The rules of the ant model tbe coulomb force in newtons
Move = a point charge displaced due to electric field
Rotate = a point charge rotating under a magnetic field (spin)
flip colour = photon emit and absorb event.

psi delta holds the total sum of all point charges
Psi theta is the photon move and rotate
The second iteration function is the photon even
The whole equation is based on schroedingers equation with time and position fixed as a constant which is why x and omega t are absent as they are unity.